# How to slice AVC/H.264 frames on android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, android-mediacodec, android-mediaprojection

My network MTU is limited to only 0xFFFF bytes. That is mostly OK with 800 x 480 resolution but sometimes exceeds, causing lost of frames.

I managed to lower the NAL max size by lowering resolution and bitrate but that greatly reduced image quality.

As i tried to overcome this issue, i encountered SLICES.
If i understand correctly, normally each frame is made from one SLICE NAL but that can be split into several, thus lowering NAL size.

On android i found the `KEY_SLICE_HEIGHT` and `KEY_STRIDE` but they did not influence in any way on the max NAL size, no matter the configuration.

As always, android suggest very little help or documentation and so i am trying to solve this issue for a week now and without any results.

```
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 4000000);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PROFILE,MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileBaseline);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_LEVEL,MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCLevel51);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SLICE_HEIGHT, (height / 2));
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_STRIDE, (width / 4));
```

Comment: After long time that i tried to slice the image i found it is not easy (if at all possible). Which made me question if the protocol i am using is in fact unable to send larger packages and It turns out that it can! When larger then 512, protocol had its own way of splitting the package